# How to store VPN credentials automatically in Keychain

Tags: password, keychain, vpn

I have to constantly connect to a VPN (I do this without problems) for work reasons.

The real problem comes when I open any browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc.) or applications like Slack, because a specific prompt for each application appears asking me again for these credentials.

I used to connect to the VPN and after entering the credentials for the first time they were automatically stored in the Keychain. But I had to update them and they are no longer stored.

I have tried storing them manually, but I am not able to give AuthBrokerAgent access to get them by itself, so I have not achieved anything.

Here you can find some technical details:

- **OS version**: macOS Catalina 10.15.6
- **VPN client**: FortiClient 6.0.9.162

Any suggestions why macOS no longer automatically stores these credentials on the Keychain?

Comment: Any details you can share on the exact  version of macOS and  If you have third party vpn software? Editing this in the body of the question is an upideal update to make if no one answers this or you don’t get useful answers.